# Read file garbled when using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, android, java-io, randomaccessfile

First, I use this code to write two lines in a file :

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\n");
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "test1.txt";
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");

randomAccessFile.writeUTF("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
randomAccessFile.write(lineSeparator.getBytes());
randomAccessFile.writeUTF("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
randomAccessFile.write(lineSeparator.getBytes());

randomAccessFile.close();
```

After writing the file, I read the file :

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
int i = 0;
String line;
while ((line = randomAccessFile.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.i("log", (i++)+" : "+line);
}
randomAccessFile.close();
```

But the strange things happened, every line starts with a `��`, I don't know what it is.

The full logs :

```
07-13 07:21:41.027 1138-1138/? I/log: 0 : ��aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
07-13 07:21:41.027 1138-1138/? I/log: 1 : ��bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

What is the garbled string, is that the line separator? And, How can I read the file correctly?

---

I tried use `writeChars` instead of `writeUTF`, but more garbled chars come into the log :

```
07-13 08:14:26.352 16821-16821/? I/log: 0 : ��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a��a
07-13 08:14:26.352 16821-16821/? I/log: 1 : ��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b��b
```

Comment: Use writeChars instead of the UTF8 write

Comment: @ScaryWombat Unless the data contains line terminators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
randomAccessFile.writeUTF("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
randomAccessFile.write(lineSeparator.getBytes());
randomAccessFile.writeUTF("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
randomAccessFile.write(lineSeparator.getBytes());
randomAccessFile.close();
```

The only way to read that would be:

```
String aaa = randomAccessFile.readUTF();
randomAccessFile.readFully(lineSeparator.getBytes());
String bbb = randomAccessFile.readUTF();
randomAccessFile.readFully(lineSeparator.getBytes());
```

It will be seen that writing the line separator was a complete waste of time and space.

In short, `writeUTF()` writes data that can only be read by `readUTF()`.

See the Javadoc.